# Flutter Shared Preferences with Provider

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am pulling product information with provider to the statefulwidget table called cart page.

```
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<Count>(context,listen: false)
        .addItem(
          items[index].name,
          1,
          items[index].price,
          items[index].imagePath);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
    Text(items[index].count.toString()),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<Count>(context, listen: false)
        .removeItem(items[index]);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I installed the shared_preferences package to prevent these products from being lost after the program is closed and opened.
When the elevated button is pressed, I save the products that appear on the page with the _saveorder method.

```
              onPressed: () {
                _saveOrder(items);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
                // onPressed event
              },
```

save order  code =

```
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final orders = prefs.getStringList('orders') ?? [];

    final orderDetails = cartItems.map((item) {
      return '${item.name},${item.count},${item.price},${item.imagePath}';
    }).join(';');

    orders.add(orderDetails);
    await prefs.setStringList('orders', orders);
  }
```

When the application is opened again, I want the product information registered with saveorder to be initstate with the loadorders method, but it does not work

```
  Count countObject = Count();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadOrders();
  }

  Future<void> _loadOrders() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final orders = prefs.getStringList('orders') ?? [];


    List<CartItem> cartItems = [];
    for (String order in orders) {
      List<String> orderDetails = order.split(',');
      cartItems.add(CartItem(
        name: orderDetails[0],
        count: int.parse(orderDetails[1]),
        price: double.parse(orderDetails[2]),
        imagePath: orderDetails[3],
      ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data from `SharedPreferences` is an asynchronous operation. You can handle that using `Futures` and [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

You can use this pattern as follow:

```dart
Future<List<CartItem>> _loadOrders() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final orders = prefs.getStringList('orders') ?? [];
    List<CartItem> cartItems = [];
    for (String order in orders) {
      List<String> orderDetails = order.split(',');
      cartItems.add(CartItem(
        name: orderDetails[0],
        count: int.parse(orderDetails[1]),
        price: double.parse(orderDetails[2]),
        imagePath: orderDetails[3],
    ));
    return cartItems; // Make sure to return a value here  
}
```

Pass the future from this function to an instance of FutureBuilder. It will rebuild the widget whenthe future completes.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadOrders(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          // Checking if future is resolved
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var items = snapshot.data as List<CartItem>;
              // ... build your widget as usual here...
          }
    );
}
```

Comment: How do I add future builder here?
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var items = Provider.of<Count>(context).items; // items öğesini okuyoruz
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(...